# How to tell if CBCentralManager is still processing scanForPeripheralsWithServices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

Is there a way to tell if the `CBCentralManager` is busy doing a `scanForPeripheralsWithServices`? I tried looking at the state, but nothing seems to indicate that it's busy scanning.

Comment: There is a not-so-bad example of how to implement this in [RFduino iOS code repo](https://github.com/RFduino/RFduino).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property of `CBCentralManager` that indicates whether it is currently scanning for peripherals.  You need to keep track of this yourself.

Typically you would implement your Bluetooth functions in a class and you can add a boolean property to this class which you set to true when you call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` and false when you call `stopScan`.